# How to send regular queries to an external server through async servlets?

Tags: java, asynchronous, web, tomcat, servlets

### Essential Information:

I'm prototyping an e-commerce web application where I use an API to redirect the client to an external server for safe payment (that's like PayPal, but local and much more used here) through their API. I'm using their sandbox environment to test it. I'm using NetBeans 8.2 IDE, Tomcat 8.0.27, Java EE 7 Web. I'm not using any framework, but I'm using the MVC design pattern with servlets as controllers and JSPs in the view level.

The client is supposed to have a Safe Purchase account, so my web application send some order info (e.g. client email, list of products and their prices), then the client pays the order and gets redirected to my website. When it redirects to my website, the Safe Purchase API sends a transaction code to my application, so I can use it to make transaction queries to get the transaction status (if it has been paid or not). I have to change manually the transaction status on the sandbox environment. Their API can also send a notification code to notify my application if the transaction status has changed, but with no additional info, so I can make the same query using the notification code instead. Since their notifications are sent in unchangable intervals, I'm focusing on making regular queries to get the statusId of the transaction, thus I thought about doing it through a different thread.

I've searched how to do it properly and found out info about async servlets. Every example of async servlet, though, uses it in a different way, so it was hard to find out the right way of doing a task like that. I've also read on some forums that Tomcat has some problems with threads, but I can't change the container now, since development is reaching the final stage and I got no time to fix possible problems caused by changing the container. I managed to run on Tomcat some simple examples that hadn't run until I added `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` to the HTTPMonitorFilter to the web.xml located on CATALINA_BASE. Disabling HTTPMonitorFilter also doesn't change a thing. So I suppose the problem here is not Tomcat (yet), but I may be wrong.

---

### Further Information

If you have patience to try to find out what I'm doing wrong, I'll thank you so much, so I detailed some info.

#### Error Messages

On browser I get this error:

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Calling [asyncStart()] is not valid for a request with Async state [MUST_COMPLETE]

    type Exception report

    message Calling [asyncStart()] is not valid for a request with Async state [MUST_COMPLETE]

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling [asyncStart()] is not valid for a request with Async state [MUST_COMPLETE]
        org.apache.coyote.AsyncStateMachine.asyncStart(AsyncStateMachine.java:197)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:801)
        org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:380)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1619)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1037)
        javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:392)
        javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:392)
        javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:392)
        controller.checkout_safepurchase.SearchTransactionAsyncServlet.service(SearchTransactionAsyncServlet.java:48)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        controller.checkout_safepurchase.SearchTransactionAsyncServlet.service(SearchTransactionAsyncServlet.java:115)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        controller.order.ProcessOrderServlet.service(ProcessOrderServlet.java:95)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 logs.
    Apache Tomcat/8.0.27
```

On the log of Tomcat I get this:

```
    07-Mar-2021 07:22:34.117 SEVERE [http-nio-443-exec-32] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [ProcessOrderServlet] in context with path [/onlinestore] threw exception
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling [asyncStart()] is not valid for a request with Async state [MUST_COMPLETE]
        at org.apache.coyote.AsyncStateMachine.asyncStart(AsyncStateMachine.java:197)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:801)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:380)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setStarted(AsyncContextImpl.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1619)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1037)
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:392)
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:392)
        at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:392)
        at controller.checkout_safepurchase.SearchTransactionAsyncServlet.service(SearchTransactionAsyncServlet.java:48)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
        at controller.checkout_safepurchase.SearchTransactionAsyncServlet.service(SearchTransactionAsyncServlet.java:115)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
        at controller.order.ProcessOrderServlet.service(ProcessOrderServlet.java:95)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

### Main Codes

The web application is obviously huge, but here you are the main 3 classes related to the errors.

#### Some Code Explanation

  **ProcessOrderServlet (Controller level):**
  The objective of this class is registering the order on the database. It does it well if I don't dispatch a request to the SearchTransactionAsyncServlet, but I'm doing it in order to handle the async task of making transaction status queries. I'm getting back information from the form used to make the checkout by setting session attributes before it redirects to Safe Purchase website. If I dispatch the request to SearchTransactionAsyncServlet, it still registers the order on database, but it doesn't empty the shopping cart.

  **SearchTransactionAsyncServlet (Controller Level):**
  This class tries to implement the async methods. Its objective is to make transaction queries for at least 30 s and, if it receives a response that the payment is approved before 30 s passed, it should stop making queries and register the order as "paid". I'm just trying to make it run, that's why I didn't add any other action to listener, just tried to print what happens to learn how it worked, but it's not printing anything. It gives me the above errors, though. According to Tomcat console, it is trying to make the transaction status query every 5 seconds as intended (set in the class SearchTransactionByCode). It's not getting the transaction status when I change it on sandbox, though, and it keeps trying to make the query indefinitely even if I've set timeout = 30 s. Of course, it's not registering the order as paid as well.

  **SearchTransactionByCode (Model level):**
  It contains the runnable method to make the transaction status query that's used as parameter to the start method of AsyncContext. It's intended to make a query every 5 s until it gets statusId = 3 (which means "payment approved").

#### ProcessOrderServlet

```
    package controller.order;

    import safepurchase.api.SafePurchase;
    import safepurchase.api.credential.Credential;
    import safepurchase.api.transaction.search.TransactionDetail;
    import static configuration.Configuration.SELLER_EMAIL;
    import static configuration.Configuration.SELLER_TOKEN;
    import static configuration.Configuration.ENV;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import model.shoppingcart.CartItem;
    import model.order.OrderLogicMethods;


    public class ProcessOrderServlet extends HttpServlet {

        /**
         * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
         * methods.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    
            String transactionCode = null;
            Boolean paid = null;
            if (request.getParameter("transactionCode") != null && request.getParameter("transactionCode").trim().length() > 0) {
                transactionCode = request.getParameter("transactionCode");
            }
            try {
                final SafePurchase safePurchase = SafePurchase.instance(Credential.sellerCredential(SELLER_EMAIL,
              SELLER_TOKEN), ENV);
        
                TransactionDetail transaction = safePurchase.transactions().search().byCode(transactionCode);
                System.out.println(transaction);
                System.out.println(transaction.getStatus().getStatusId());
                System.out.println(transaction.getStatus().getStatus());
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            if (session != null && session.getAttribute("login") != null) {
                String client_login = (String) session.getAttribute("login");
                List<CartItem> cartItems = (List<CartItem>) session.getAttribute("cartItems");
                String notes = (String) session.getAttribute("notes");
                String scheduling = (String) session.getAttribute("scheduling");
                String orderPassword = (String) session.getAttribute("orderPassword");
                String purchaseState = (String) session.getAttribute("purchaseState");
                Double totalAmount = (Double) session.getAttribute("totalAmount");
                String store_login = (String) session.getAttribute("store_login");

                OrderLogicMethods orderLogic = new OrderLogicMethods();
                String errorMessage = "";
                boolean purchaseSuccess = false;

                try {
                    purchaseSuccess = orderLogic.registerOrder(cartItems, notes, scheduling, orderPassword, purchaseState, totalAmount, client_login, store_login, transactionCode, paid);
                    if (!purchaseSuccess) {
                        errorMessage = "It was not possible to process your order";
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
                }

                if (purchaseSuccess) {
                    request.setAttribute("orderPassword", orderPassword);
                    request.setAttribute("message", "Waiting for payment confirmation...");
                    request.setAttribute("transactionCode", transactionCode);
                    session.removeAttribute("cartItems");
                    session.removeAttribute("notes");
                    session.removeAttribute("scheduling");
                    session.removeAttribute("orderPassword");
                    session.removeAttribute("purchaseState");
                    session.removeAttribute("totalAmount");
                    session.removeAttribute("store_login");
                    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("SearchTransactionAsyncServlet?emptyCart=true");//it's not emptying the shopping cart as well
                    //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("IndexServlet?emptyCart=true");//commenting the line above and uncommenting this line make the order get registered on database and the shopping cart empty
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    request.setAttribute("message", errorMessage);
                    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("IndexServlet");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("message", "You must log in before making the checkout");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("IndexServlet");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
        }

    }
```

#### SearchTransactionAsyncServlet

```
    package controller.checkout_safepurchase;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
    import javax.servlet.AsyncEvent;
    import javax.servlet.AsyncListener;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import model.checkout_safepurchase.SearchTransactionByCode;
    import model.order.OrderLogicMethods;

    @WebServlet(name = "SearchTransactionAsyncServlet", urlPatterns = "/SearchTransactionAsyncServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    public class SearchTransactionAsyncServlet extends HttpServlet {

        /**
         * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
         * methods.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

            Boolean paid = null;
            String transactionCode = null;
            String orderPassword = null;
            if (request.getParameter("transactionCode") != null && request.getParameter("transactionCode").trim().length() > 0) {
                transactionCode = request.getParameter("transactionCode");
            }
            if (request.getParameter("orderPassword") != null && request.getParameter("orderPassword").trim().length() > 0) {
                orderPassword = request.getParameter("orderPassword");
            }
            SearchTransactionByCode searchTransactionByCode = new SearchTransactionByCode("transactionCode");
            AsyncContext actx = request.startAsync(request, response);
            actx.setTimeout(30 * 1000);
            actx.addListener(new AsyncListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("It completed with statusId: " + searchTransactionByCode.getStatusId());
                }

                @Override
                public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("It got timeout with statusId: " + searchTransactionByCode.getStatusId());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("It got an error with statusId: " + searchTransactionByCode.getStatusId());
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("It started the async task with statusId: " + searchTransactionByCode.getStatusId());
                }

            });
    
            actx.start(searchTransactionByCode);
            actx.complete();
            System.out.println("Approved payment? " + searchTransactionByCode.isPaymentApproved());
            paid = searchTransactionByCode.isPaymentApproved();

            /*String notificationCode = null;
            if (request.getParameter("notificationCode") != null && request.getParameter("notificationCode").trim().length() > 0) {
                notificationCode = request.getParameter("notificationCode");
            }*/ // this part is commented because I also plan to wait for the notificationCode sent by the server of Safe Purchase when the payment status changes to make queries; should I make another servlet for that?

            OrderLogicMethods orderLogic = new OrderLogicMethods();
            String errorMessage = "";
            boolean updateSuccess = false;

            if (paid) {
                try {
                    updateSuccess = orderLogic.updatePaymentStatus(transactionCode, paid);
                    if (!updateSuccess) {
                        errorMessage = "It was not possible to update the payment status";
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
                }
                if (updateSuccess) {
                    request.setAttribute("message", "Your order was successfully done. Your purchase is being prepared. Your password is: " + orderPassword + ". The transaction code is: " + transactionCode);
                    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("IndexServlet");//here I was assuming the cart was sucessfully emptied in the previous servlet
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    request.setAttribute("message", errorMessage);
                    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("IndexServlet");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("orderPassword", orderPassword);
                request.setAttribute("message", "Payment not done yet");
                request.setAttribute("transactionCode", transactionCode);
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("SearchTransactionAsyncServlet");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }

        }

    }
```

#### SearchTransactionByCode

```
    package model.checkout_safepurchase;

    import safepurchase.api.SafePurchase;
    import safepurchase.api.credential.Credential;
    import safepurchase.api.transaction.search.TransactionDetail;
    import static configuration.Configuration.SELLER_EMAIL;
    import static configuration.Configuration.SELLER_TOKEN;
    import static configuration.Configuration.ENV;

    public class SearchTransactionByCode implements Runnable {

        private String transactionCode;
        private int statusId;
        private boolean paymentApproved;

        public int getStatusId() {
            return statusId;
        }

        public boolean isPaymentApproved() {
            return paymentApproved;
        }

        public SearchTransactionByCode(String transactionCode) {
            this.transactionCode = transactionCode;
        }

       @Override
        public void run() {
            while (statusId != 3) {//when statusId is 3, it means it's approved 
                try {
                    final SafePurchase safePurchase = SafePurchase.instance(Credential.sellerCredential(SELLER_EMAIL,
                            SELLER_TOKEN), ENV);

                    TransactionDetail transaction = pagSeguro.transactions().search().byCode(transactionCode);
                    statusId = transaction.getStatus().getStatusId();
                    System.out.println(transaction);
                    System.out.println(statusId);
                    System.out.println(transaction.getStatus().getStatus());
                    Thread.sleep(5000);// this was intended to make the transaction query every 5 seconds
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            paymentApproved = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A small remark: Tomcat 8.0 is unsupported since [a couple of years](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html). [Migrate](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html) to Tomcat 8.5 or higher, if you can.

Comment: Another small remark: look up "web sockets" instead of trying to reinvent it.

Answer (score 0):

You use `AsyncContext` in the wrong way: basically all the code in `SearchTransactionAsyncServlet#service` **after** the `actx.start(searchTransactionByCode)` call should be in the `SearchTransactionByCode` runnable. Also you are not allowed to use `RequestDispatcher#forward` method, but you should use `AsyncContext#dispatch` instead.

What happens now is:

1. You put the request into async mode through `ServletRequest#startAsync`. This means that the end of the `SearchTransactionAsyncServlet#service` method execution will not cause a response to be sent automatically to the client,
2. You call `AsyncContext#start` method, that will execute `SearchTransationByCode` in another thread. However this is **not** a blocking call, so the execution will continue.
3. You call `AsyncContext#complete`, which closes the response,
4. You forward the request to the same servlet,
5. You call `ServletRequest#startAsync` again, which is not allowed:

> if this request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not support asynchronous operations (that is, isAsyncSupported() returns false), or if this method is called again without any asynchronous dispatch (resulting from one of the AsyncContext.dispatch() methods), is called outside the scope of any such dispatch, or is called again within the scope of the same dispatch, or if the response has already been closed

(cf. [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#startAsync--)).

**Edit:** After the refactoring, the `SearchTransactionByCode` will look like this:

```java
public class SearchTransactionByCode implements Runnable {

        private final AsyncContext ctx;

        public SearchTransactionByCode(AsyncContext ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

       @Override
        public void run() {
            final ServletRequest req = ctx.getRequest();
            int statusId = 0;
            while (statusId != 3) {//when statusId is 3, it means it's approved 
                // ... whatever you need to verify the payment
            }
            req.setAttribute("message", ...);
            ctx.dispatch("/IndexServlet");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped me a lot to understand what documentation meant. Without RequestDispatcher I can't manage to send parameters to the JSP, though. I've been reading a lot, but I couldn't find a way to do the same through AsyncContext#dispatch

Comment: `AsyncContext#dispatch` works like `RequestDispatcher#forward`, but uses the `ServletRequest` contained in the `AsyncContext`. I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry... I've tried... it's not working... I'm using request.getParameter("message") in JSP. It's getting "null"

Comment: You should use `getAttribute`, not `getParameter`. BTW since JSP 2.0 [EL expressions](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsf-el.html#GJDDD) are preferred to scriptlets `<% ... %>`. You can use the `${message}` expression.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to fix it and now it throws java.lang.NullPointerException at the line of req.setAttribute...